# python concurrent futures executing even on unhandled exceptions

Tags: python, multithreading

Consider the following code snippet:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


def throw_func(a):
    print(a)
    time.sleep(10)
    raise ValueError(a)
    

params = list(range(5000))
    
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    future_to_row = {executor.submit(throw_func, param): param for param in params}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_row):
        row = future_to_row[future]
        future.result()
```

It seems like when there is an unhandled exception, the program still tries to complete all the submitted futures.

And no exception messages are printed on the screen.

Why is this happening? How do I make sure that when there is an unhandled exception, the program will exit?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation for one of my projects, this is the solution I came up with back then. Unfortunately, there is no built-in mechanism in the `concurrent.futures` module to immediately halt all running threads in an executor. You can create a custom thread class that checks for an external "stop" signal and then implement a mechanism like an event that can be set when an exception occurs. Handle exceptions within each thread and signal other threads to stop when one occurs. I modified my solution for your use case:

```
import threading
import time

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args, stop_event):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.stop_event = stop_event
        
    # Signal other threads to stop for exception
    def run(self):
        try:
            self.func(*self.args)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception in thread: {e}")
            self.stop_event.set()  

def main(a, stop_event):
    print(f"Thread {a} started")
    time.sleep(10)
    if a == 2:
        raise ValueError(a)
    if stop_event.is_set():
        print(f"Thread {a} stopping early")
        return
    print(f"Thread {a} finished")

stop_event = threading.Event()


threads = [StoppableThread(main, (i, stop_event), stop_event) for i in range(5)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All threads completed or stopped")
```

Output:

```
Thread 0 started
Thread 1 started
Thread 2 started
Thread 3 started
Thread 4 started
Thread 0 finished
Exception in thread: 2
Thread 1 stopping early
Thread 3 stopping early
Thread 4 stopping early
All threads completed or stopped
```

This is probably not the best way to approach this, so let me know if you can find any better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The executor has a [`shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) functionality. Read carefully the doc to understand how to tune the parameters to better achieve the desired result.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    
    future_to_row = {executor.submit(throw_func, param): param for param in params}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_row):

        try:
            future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print(row, e)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)
            break
    
    # not needed in real situation
    print("checking that the shutdown actually did its job")
    print(all(future.done() for future in future_to_row))
```

output

```
0
1
2
3
4
1 # <- 1st repeated value is the 1st function to be finished, hence the exception. All next are pending futures
5
2306
checking that the shutdown actually did its job
True
```

---

Answering to the questions in the OP:

> "It seems like when there is an unhandled exception, the program still
> tries to complete all the submitted futures. [...]
> Why is this happening? "

`concurrent` is a pure Python module, [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.12/Lib/concurrent), it depends on other more "primitive" modules such as `threading`, also written in Python [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/threading.py).

From the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) doc: *"If the `run()` method raises an exception, `threading.excepthook()` is called to handle it. By default, `threading.excepthook()` ignores silently `SystemExit`"*

I haven't found any trace of `excepthook` in `concurrent` so I assume is also a default, so they are *silently ignored*. The reason why it in the next section.

> "How do I make sure that when there is an unhandled exception, the program will exit?"

an inspection if an occurrence of an exception takes place in any future object can be done with the [`future.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.exception) method: *"Return the exception raised by the call* or None if the call completed without raising"

Here the details of the body of the loop

```
    # ...
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_row):

        present_exception = future.exception()
        # check if an exception occurs in the task
        if isinstance(present_exception, Exception): # or if present_exception is not None:
            # abort all other tasks
            executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)

            # check the shutdown: not needed in real situation
            print("checking that the shutdown actually did its job")
            print(all(future.done() for future in future_to_row))
            
            # stop the program raising an exception
            raise present_exception
        
        # process the result only after the exception!
        future.result()
    
    # other things to do if no exceptions are caught
    pass
```

Output (program exit with error traceback)

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
2872
2871
checking that the shutdown actually did its job
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise present_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/main.py", line 8, in throw_func
    raise ValueError(a)
ValueError: 0
```

---

Remark on the `exit code`:

In case an exception occurs,

my **first** implementation will exit the program with `exit code 0` so "without" error due to the `break`

```
        try:
            future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)
            break
```

but if you want an `exit code 1` do smt like this

```
        try:
            future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)
            raise future.exception()
```

or

```
        if future.exception() is not None:
            executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)
            raise future.exception()
        
        future.result() # must be called AFTER checking for exceptions
```